# Qprocess arguments when sending command to git

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qprocess

I'm using pyQT5 and I need to run a git-command through Qprocess.

The command I'm trying to run is:

*'git clone --depth 1 --branch ' + self.comboBox.currentText() + ' file:///' + dunepath + barepath + 'repo/repodir | tee log/git.log'*

I can't get it to work. I understand that I need to put the arguments in a list (Qstringlist?), but when I try that, it seems like '--depth' is changed to 'depth'

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

I tried many variants, one being just:

self.p.start(['git clone','--depth 1','--branch ' + self.comboBox.currentText(),'file:///' + dunepath + barepath','repo/repodir | tee log/git.log'])

I'm completely new to using Qprocess so bare with me please...

UPDATE:
I solved it by using:
self.p.start("/bin/sh", ["-c","git clone --depth 1 --branch " + self.comboBox.currentText() + " file:///" + dunepath + bare + " repo/repodir | tee log/git.log"])

Comment: Show the full code that you used. There are actually *two* commands there (`git` and `tee`) which are joined by a pipe.

Comment: There's no overload of [start](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) that takes just a list.